# PHP mutiple IF comparsion on 2 or 3 variables that are set TRUE or FALSE in a single IF statment

Tags: php

how do I simply do a multiple if comparison on say 2 or 3 variables that are set to either TRUE or FALSE in a single if statement

I have a few variables that are set in my code to either true or false, and at the end of my code i want to do something like

```
if($soldby_error === TRUE) OR ($InStock_error === TRUE) OR ($Other_error === TRUE) 
{
    echo "do this code";
}
```

so if a true comes up in there, for any of the variables,  the code is run

what would be the correct way to write the if statement like that do i need to use  || && OR ????

```
//sold by check
$haystack = strtolower($soldby_data);
$needle = "mysite";
$soldby_by_check = strpos($haystack,$needle);
if($soldby_by_check === false) 
{
    // string needle NOT found in haystack 
    echo '<br><h1>THERE IS a sold by error</h1><br>';
    $soldby_error = TRUE;
}
else {
 // string needle found
     $soldby_error = FALSE;
}

//in stock error check
$haystack = strtolower($stock_data);
$needle = 'out of stock|in stock on';
if (preg_match('/'.$needle.'/', $haystack)) // if true - item is OUT of stock
{
    // string needle found item is temp out of stock / not sold or error
    echo '<br><h1>OUT OF stock error</h1><br>';
    $InStock_error = TRUE;               
}
else {
    // string needle NOT found in haystack - ok / in stock 
    $InStock_error = FALSE;
}        

// now do a update if required  THIS IS WHERE I NEED THE MUTIPLE IF STATEMENT CHECK
 if($soldby_error === TRUE) {

    echo '<br><h1>THERE IS a sold by error</h1><br>';
    $update_now = TRUE;
    if ($currentpricecheck < "49.99") {$update_price = $currentprice_tripled;}
    if ($currentpricecheck > "50.00") {$update_price = $currentprice_doubled;}
}
```

Comment: You have to use `&&` operator! like: `if(var1 && var2 && ...)` You're on a good way! Also as a reference you can use: php.net

Comment: Actually you have to use the `||` operator if you're trying to match any condition with "OR". See [logical operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php)

Comment: @sjagr he need AND operator since he need code to be skipped if one of vars is false

Comment: From his phrasing, it sounds like he needs the && operator. "so if a false comes up in there, for any of the variables, the code is not run"

Comment: Poster needs to wrap the whole expression in braces, not just the individual tests

Comment: @lolbas @hofan41 and yet he contradicts himself by asking for `if($soldby_error === TRUE) OR ($InStock_error === TRUE) OR ($Other_error === TRUE)`

Comment: there is no need to compare boolean variables with TRUE or FALSE, it is a bad habit. simply write if ($variable) {..}

Comment: @sjagr seems like we came across op misunderstanding of logical operators!

Comment: @lolbas IRONIC: Yep very bad habit, we all hope the variable never will be 1! (x === TRUE)

Comment: thanks everyone for the comments cleaned my code up abit better now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if($soldby_error || $InStock_error || $Other_error)
{
  //At least one of the variables is true
}
```

If you want to execute code when any of the above variables is true then you would write your if like this. If you want to execute code only when ALL variables are true, just replace || with &&.

Based on this line in your question "so if a false comes up in there, for any of the variables, the code is not run and the if statment is skipped past" it seems like you want the latter option so use the above statement with && instead of ||.

Comment: sorry I meant to say ''so if a true comes up in there, for any of the variables, the code is run'' just edited the op

Comment: Then you would want to use the if statement I wrote at the top, that will execute the code in the {} if any of those three variables are true.